# Sent (null) Correlation Id is not same as received (null)

Tags: java, sql-server, correlation, paas

I have a Spring Boot (2.7.6) / Java (8) application that's creating a SQL Server JDBC data source, that gets a valid connection. But, whenever I get the connection from the data source to select some data I get the following lines in my log file:

```
Attempting to get a test connection.
c.microsoft.aad.msal4j.WSTrustResponse   : Found token of type: urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion
com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.HttpHelper      : [Correlation ID: null] Sent (null) Correlation Id is not same as received (null).
com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.HttpHelper      : [Correlation ID: null] Sent (null) Correlation Id is not same as received (cb6846d3-895e-4693-87e0-f72ef3262fd1)
Got a connection!!!!
```

I'm running the code locally, and connecting to a PAAS SQL Server DB running in a cloud. Here are the pertinent lines of code used to create the data source:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource ss = new com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource();
ss.setUser(dbUser);
ss.setPassword(AESUtility.decrypt(dbPassword));
ss.setServerName(dbServername);
ss.setDatabaseName(dbDatabasename);
ss.setPortNumber(Integer.parseInt(dbPortNumber));
ss.setAuthentication("ActiveDirectoryPassword");
ss.setEncrypt("true");
ss.setTrustServerCertificate(true);

System.out.println("Attempting to get a test connection.");
connection = ss.getConnection();
System.out.println("Got a connection!!!!");
```

The JDBC driver is version:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.1.jre8</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: From the error, it looks like the problem is when communicating to a web service, not when communicating with the SQL server. Since your using PAAS SQL, it's probably getting a security token via a web service. The only thing I found on Spring Boot is this article which describes getting and setting a Correlation ID. https://dzone.com/articles/implementing-correlation-ids

Comment: Thank you @TimJaros for the suggestion and link. But, I still feel it's the ss.getConnection() call that's generating the correlation messages. I've added some System.out statements around the getConnection() call to help illustrate my point.

Comment: From the [MS Documentation for JDBC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connecting-using-azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver16#connect-using-activedirectorypassword-authentication-mode) it looks like you're doing it right. Perhaps add the "You have successfully logged on as: ..." output method from the documentation, after the connection is established. Perhaps the Correlation ID error is a red herring.

Comment: Thanks for the great link. I've copied it into my source code for the next person who has to support the code. I get the 3 lines of output during the call to ss.getConnection(). I don't even need to make a call using the Connection object. I think the 3 lines of output are harmless as I'm able to both read and write to the DB without a problem. My problem is that my log files are going to be cluttered with tens of thousands of these sets of 3 lines per day.

Comment: I'm hoping there's a method on the SQLServerDataSource object that I can call to fix this, but so far I'm unsuccessful in finding any method or combination of methods. Here's a link to the API: [SQLServerDataSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/reference/sqlserverdatasource-class?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: Maybe now that you know what's going on, you can revise this question or post a new one; perhaps entitled "How to suppress erroneous JDBC correlation ID messages?" or similar.